# Which package I have to add for using the method XQueryUtil.xquery() , and from where can I download that?

Tags: java, xquery

I want to use this method `xquery();` whose argument and return type is as follows ...

```
Node result = XQueryUtil.xquery(doc, "/PERIODIC_TABLE/ATOM[NAME = 'Zinc']").get(0);
```

So can anybody help me for using this type of method. It is giving error that does not find the symbol `XQueryUtil`, So please help me which package I should use and from where I can download that jar file ?

Comment: Doesn't it have a package name?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Nux](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux/), which has *exactly* your example in its [JavaDoc](https://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux/api/nux/xom/xquery/XQueryUtil.html#xquery%28nu.xom.Node,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yaa exactly right, But when I put the .jar files and source files to netbeans , that gave a lot of errors ?